# Calculate percentage with group by dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to calculate the percentage for each character colname in my dataframe but the percentage isn't good.

My code :

```
for(i in names(which((sapply(creditDF,class) == "character")))){
  distribution <- creditDF %>%
   group_by_at(.vars = i) %>%
   summarise(value = n(),
          percent = value/sum(value)) %>%
  select(label = i, value, percent)
}
```

Résult :

```
 label value percent
 <chr> <int>   <dbl>
1 chéquier   autorisé   415       1
2 chéquier   interdit    53       1
```

Normally for the first lines the percentage is 415/468*100.

How can I fix my problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we need to `ungroup` to get the `sum` of the whole 'value' column i.e

```
--                       %>%
  group_by_at(.vars = i) %>%
  summarise(value = n() %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(percent = value/sum(value)) %>%
  select(label = i, value, percent)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) . I didn't know this fonction.